# Django NoReverseMatch Reverse for DetailView

Tags: python, django, detailview

My application is throwing an error when I redirect back to a detail view in Django 1.5.

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'InventoryPlotDetailView' with arguments
>   '(3,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

It's getting the correct forestinventoryplot_id, but it seems that the detail view doesn't know how to handle the argument.  If I access the detail view manually (`http://[server]/geoapp/inventory_plot/detail/3/`), it works as expected. Below are the relevant bits and pieces, any advice?

**Views.py:**

```
class InventoryPlotDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = ForestInventoryPlot.objects.all()
    template_name = 'geoapp/forestinventoryplot_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'plot_detail'

def InventoryDataAdd(request, forestinventoryplot_id=1):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = InventoryDataForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            new_data = form.save()          
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('geoapp:InventoryPlotDetailView', args=(new_data.forestinventoryplot_id,)))
    else: 
        initial_data = {'forestinventoryplot' : forestinventoryplot_id}
        form = InventoryDataForm(initial=initial_data)    
        return render(request, 'geoapp/forestinventorydata_add.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index$', views.Index),
    url(r'^$', views.Index),
    url(r'^inventory_plot/add/$', views.InventoryPlotAdd, name='inventory_plot_add'),
    url(r'^inventory_plot/edit/(?P<forestinventoryplot_id>\d+)$', views.InventoryPlotEdit, name='inventory_plot_edit'),
    url(r'^inventory_plot/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.InventoryPlotDelete, name='inventory_plot_delete'),
    url(r'^map/$', views.map_page),
    url(r'^map2/$', views.map2_page),
    url(r'^inventory_plot/$', views.InventoryPlotListView.as_view(), name='inventory_plot_list'),
    url(r'^inventory_plot/detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.InventoryPlotDetailView.as_view(), name='plot_detail'),
    url(r'^inventory_data/add/$', views.InventoryDataAdd, name='inventory_data_add'),
    url(r'^inventory_plot/(?P<forestinventoryplot_id>\d+)/add_data/$', views.InventoryDataAdd, name='inventory_data_add'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', views.logout_view),
    url(r'^home/$', views.Home, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^inventory_data/add/(?P<forestinventoryplot_id>\d+)/$', views.InventoryDataAdd, name='inventory_data_addition'),
  )
```

**Models.py:**

```
class ForestInventoryPlot(models.Model):
    forestinventoryplot_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    plot_area_ft2 = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    plot_radius_ft = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)
    plot_length_x_ft = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)
    plot_length_y_ft = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)
    plot_geometry = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    geometry = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True, blank=True)
    elevation = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    position_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    plot_create_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    class Meta:
            db_table = 'forest_inventory_plot'
            ordering = ["forestinventoryplot_id"]
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.forestinventoryplot_id)

class ForestInventoryData(models.Model):
    forestinventorydata_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    forestinventoryplot = models.ForeignKey('ForestInventoryPlot', null=True, blank=True)
    tree = models.ForeignKey('Tree', null=True, blank=True)
    collection_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    dbh_in = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)
    height_ft = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'forest_inventory_data'
        ordering = ["forestinventorydata_id"]
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.forestinventorydata_id)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the name "plot_detail" as the first argument to reverse?

Comment: One other thing I noticed is pk is a named argument, so you'll want to try passing kwargs rather than args to reverse.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Nathan. I passed kwargs and changed the argument to plot_detail, as well as every combination thereof I could easily think of and still get an error: Reverse for 'plot_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found.

Comment: I just added the model definition for the two tables in question. There is a many to one relation between inventory plots and inventory data in case that information is helpful.

Comment: Have you namespaced your views? Post your full `urls.py`

Comment: Posted the full urls.py, I haven't namespaced my views.

Comment: Thanks Nathan and Burhan, it was a combination of all of the above, if you guys post answers I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view required passing the primary key as kwarg, using the name of the url.py entry (plot_detail), and using the namespace appended to it ('geoapp:plot_detail') to make things work.

```
def InventoryDataAdd(request, forestinventoryplot_id=1):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InventoryDataForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            new_data = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('geoapp:plot_detail', kwargs={'pk':new_data.forestinventoryplot_id}))
        else: 
            initial_data = {'forestinventoryplot' : forestinventoryplot_id}
            form = InventoryDataForm(initial=initial_data)
    return render(request, 'geoapp/forestinventorydata_add.html', {'form': form})
```